# Use Windows machine as network gateway

Tags: windows-7, networking, windows-10, vpn

I have two machines on the same local network (non-domain).

One of these machines runs windows 7 and has VPN client software that connects to a remote site, it runs and I can ping the remote network, access file shares and so on.

The other machine is running Windows 10, unfortunately the VPN client software is not supported on that operating system and there is no viable alternative.

Is there a way for the Windows 10 machine to use the Windows 7 machine as a gateway so I can access what the resources the VPN provides?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. What research have you done and what have you tried so far?

Comment: ICS (Internet connection sharing) might be an option.